# Use DI in asp.net core 2.0 for injecting BLL services

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have `asp.net core 2.0 Web Api` project that uses `BLL` (`Business Logic Layer`). I'm getting error when I'm trying to inject any `BLL` service as `Dependancy` in my `Controller`. I have implemented the following `Controller`:

```
namespace MyProject.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITestService _testService;

        public TestController(ITestService testService)
        {
            _testService = testService;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("get-all")]
        public List<Test> Get()
        {
            return _testService.GetTestList();
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented test service in `BLL` (separate project):

```
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        private readonly ITestEngine _testEngine;

        public TestService(ITestEngine testEngine)
        {
            _testEngine = testEngine;
        }

        public List<Test> GetTestList()
        {
            return _testEngine.GetTestList();
        }
    }
}
```

And my interface for `TestService` looks like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    public interface ITestService
    {
        List<Test> GetTestList();
    }
}
```

The `build` is `successful` but when I call `Get` method of `TestController` I'm getting the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.Infrastructure.Interface.ITestEngine' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Core.TestService'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the DI container doesn't know about your services. You need to register them manually in the `ConfigureServices` method which is in `Startup.cs`, for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Snip
    services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
}
```

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) to understand the lifetime you need for the service (i.e. scoped, singleton or transient)

Answer (score 2):

In the Startup class, you need to manually add each service you want into the DI container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // your current code goes here
    // ...

    services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
}
```

If you want this to happen automatically, you will need to add a more specialized container (like Autofac or StructureMap).